# Does "this" keyword works with Template literals?

Tags: this, template-literals

I noticed that the "this" keyword doesn't work if inside a Template Literal. Is it normal or my code has something wrong?

```
let dog = {
  name: "Spot",
  numLegs: 4,
  sayLegs: () => `This dog has ${this.numLegs} legs.`
}
```

The output is "This dog has undefined legs.", it works only if I substitute this whith the literal object name

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) Arrow Functions do not bind their own `this`.

More info is also mentioned [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own `this`.

Replacing an arrow function with regular function inside the object allows `this` to refer to the object itself.

```
let dog = {
    name: "Spot",
    numLegs: 4,
    sayLegs: function () {
        console.log(`This dog has ${this.numLegs} legs.`);
    }
};
dog.sayLegs(); // This dog has 4 legs.
```

In my opinion, using arrow functions with closures or callback functions is more preferable.
When it comes to class/object methods or constructors I choose to use regular functions.